# Kafka Streams leftJoin - only right null if no join within window

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm doing a windowed leftJoin in Kafka Streams.

I would like the join would to wait for the duration of the window before emiting result with null right side.

Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: Not at the moment. You could add a stateful `transform()` after the join, and buffer `<left,null>` results to see if they join later, and emit `<left,null>` after a "timeout" using punctuations.

Comment: Is it the approach you descibe in more detail here?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48196450/end-of-window-outer-join-with-kafkastreams

Comment: Thanks @sumek for pointing out the duplicate! Yes, it's the same thing.

Comment: It was useful for me and might be for others as I couldn't find the original question without using `transform` and `punctuation` as additional keywords. Thanks for the answer(s)!